# Accessing file with streamreader failed because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I have a .NET Core application which is multithreaded. One aspect of the application is a health check which parses a log file for errors. This is the code used to access it:

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(GetLogFile);
```

I noticed that I occasionally get this error:

> 2021-01-12 11:15:14.890Z ERROR APP=2227 COMP=3789 [16] Health check Check logs for application issues threw an unhandled exception after 96.2407ms - Logger=Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.DefaultHealthCheckService,Level=ERROR,ThreadId=16,,Exception="System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\apps\Cb.Publisher\Logs\Cb.Publisher.log' because it is being used by another process.

I changed my code to this:

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(GetLogFile));
```

In testing it I haven't encountered the issue but it occurred so rarely that I am not 100% sure it's resolved. Is my change likely to resolve this issue or is there a better way to do it?

**Additional Info**

This is the entire function:

```
private int LogLine(Regex reg)
{
    GetLogFile = DefaultLogFile.GetLogFileName();
    using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(GetLogFile));
    string line;
    int lineNo = 0;
    int errorLine = 0;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Match match = reg.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            errorLine = lineNumber;
        }
        lineNo++;
    }
    return errorLine;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `while` line in Visual Studio and run the function, then try to edit the file in Notepad I fails with the error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`.

After some investigation I'm wondering if this line could actually be the cause of my problems:

```
var fileTarget = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("file-target");
```

It's in `DefaultLogFile.GetLogFileName`:

```
public string GetLogFileName()
{
    var fileTarget = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("file-target");
    var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
    string fileName = fileTarget.FileName.Render(logEventInfo);
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        throw new Exception("Log file does not exist.");
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Is this application multi-threaded? Perhaps a brief description of the other technologies (e.g. WPF, ASP.NET Core, etc) in the application would help.

Comment: OK. I added a little more info. It's a .Net core application and is multithreaded.

Comment: In that case it’s quite possible that this could be an issue where multiple threads attempt to access this file. Do you have a lock around the file access code? Do multiple threads read from this file? The random/occasional nature of the bug you describe is typical of a threading issue. I think it would be good to post the rest of the function(s) in which this file is read from.

Answer (score 0):

You currently suggested solution will likely be enough, yes:

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(GetLogFile));
```

However, the proper solution is for you to check that the file is not being locked from wherever else you are using the file. This also means your logging framework (be it Log4Net, NLog, Serilog etc.) should be properly configured to not take an exclusive lock on the log file. I believe logging frameworks usually do not lock it from read access by default, so unless you have customized the configuration the logging framework should not be a problem.